# Mosquitto Authentication with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mqtt, mosquitto

I would like to set up an own Mosquitto broker as a docker container. 
This is not a problem since there are several ready to run containers out there.

My problem is, how can i configure mosquitto in a way, that i can store the user login credentials, for authentication against mosquitto, in a Database like mysql instead of a password file.

The background is, i would like to configure the access by a PHP script. 
Im open to other methods instead of using a mysql db.

But i think a db would be the best solution. 
Im also open to alternatives to Mosquitto. I only would like to use MQTT with a DB based user authentication.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Dockerfile that will build a container with both Mosquitto and the authentication plugin (https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug). In my case I set it up to work against a instance of MongoDB hosted in the same container, but it would not be too hard to modify it to work against a MySQL instance, either local or remote.

I've put the Dockerfile up on Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/hardillb/0ce50250d40ff6fc3d623ddb5926ec4d) as a starting reference.

Answer (score 0):

This repository comes with a pre-configured `mosquitto` broker along with a `PostgreSQL` DB `auth` where you can `add`/`edit`/`delete` users.

Link: https://github.com/vish30/docker-mosquitto

Answer (score 0):

The plugin suggested in accepted answer is abandoned!

The current go to plugin is https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth it is even suggested in the official docs.